# Azure Git Repository Add Group to Security

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops

So in exploring how to secure an entire repository to just a specific group, I inadvertently removed the "Contributors" group for the over arching "Git Repository" tree

[image]

So how do I get "Contributors" added back at the top level? None of my google searches address this specific situation. Do I simply delete the repository, recreate it, and then push the code back into it? Or is there a way from the project settings to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to add the "Contributors" back to the list, you can search for the "Contributors" in the search panel above the Groups List, just like in the below screenshot.

To reproduce the scenario, I deleted the Contributors role in my project as well like below.

[image: No Contributor Role for me either]

Once you find the Contributors, ensure to select the contributors role that is associated with the specific Project.

[image]

And make any changes to the permissions such as "Contribute" to Allow of this group on the right.

This should make the Group to re-appear in the list.

[image]

Comment: Reddy. Worked perfectly. Thanks

Comment: Sure. Glad I could help.